# Small Non-Persistent CLI LTS Ubuntus, or Small Current Ubuntu VM (not iso) distributions

Tags: server, virtualbox, guest-session

I have a (numerical CLI shell) program I want to distribute for installation into a fresh ubuntu VM.  My potential users don't know much about linux, nor do they want to know.  I want them to follow steps 1, 2, 3, ...  some of my users will then like what they see and learn to do more, but I am not responsible for this.

right now, I have to start with a virtual machine and an iso and give them instructions how to get ubuntu installations started.  it's ok, but it would be a lot nicer if I could do this without having them learn about ubuntu installation (and/or undertake the endless registrations for cloud services that provide this).

my first choice would be an Internet service without persistence, where users are essentially "guests" to current ubuntu (LTS).  it could have a time limit (1h CPU?  24h Wallclock).  at times, even I would love a sandbox like this.  if some vendor already hosts such a free service with not too much fuzz, I would appreciate pointers.  If not, if someone has set this up already and written up instructions, please point me there.

my second choice would be a small VM, skipping at least over the installation process, for the user's own machine on his own computer.

pointers appreciated.